A java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException was thrown when YAML files were accessed
Background:
I'm using openrewrite to upgrade my app from spring boot 2 to spring boot 3. I implemented some recipes in my artifact com.company:rewrite-recipe-starter:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.  My app has a application.yml file, which includes this key value pair.
ignoredPattern: ['a.b.']

Below exception happened when I executed recipes for my app
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.openrewrite.maven:rewrite-maven-plugin:5.47.0:runNoFork (default-cli) on project dcpstream-contracts: Execution default-cli of goal org.openrewrite.maven:rewrite-maven-plugin:5.47.0:runNoFork failed: Error while visiting myproject/src/main/resources/application.yml: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 4
[ERROR]   java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt(StringLatin1.java:48)
[ERROR]   java.base/java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:1513)
[ERROR]   org.openrewrite.yaml.trait.YamlReference$Matcher.determineKind(YamlReference.java:81)
[ERROR]   org.openrewrite.yaml.trait.YamlReference$Matcher.test(YamlReference.java:75)
[ERROR]   org.openrewrite.yaml.trait.YamlReference$Matcher.test(YamlReference.java:65)
[ERROR]   org.openrewrite.trait.SimpleTraitMatcher$1.preVisit(SimpleTraitMatcher.java:77)
[ERROR]   org.openrewrite.trait.SimpleTraitMatcher_1_YamlVisitor.preVisit(SimpleTraitMatcher_1_YamlVisitor.zig:81)
[ERROR]   org.openrewrite.TreeVisitor.visit(TreeVisitor.java:247)
[ERROR]   org.openrewrite.TreeVisitor.visitAndCast(TreeVisitor.java:320)
[ERROR]   org.openrewrite.yaml.YamlVisitor.visitSequenceEntry(YamlVisitor.java:105)
[ERROR]   org.openrewrite.yaml.tree.Yaml$Sequence$Entry.acceptYaml(Yaml.java:438)
[ERROR]   org.openrewrite.yaml.tree.Yaml.accept(Yaml.java:43)
[ERROR]   org.openrewrite.TreeVisitor.visit(TreeVisitor.java:250)
[ERROR]   org.openrewrite.TreeVisitor.visitAndCast(TreeVisitor.java:320)
[ERROR]   org.openrewrite.yaml.YamlVisitor.lambda$visitSequence$2(YamlVisitor.java:100)
[ERROR]   org.openrewrite.internal.ListUtils.map(ListUtils.java:243)
[ERROR]   ...
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]

Here is my mvn command with org.openrewrite.recipe:rewrite-recipe-bom:2.23.2
mvn -B org.openrewrite.maven:rewrite-maven-plugin:5.47.0:runNoFork \
-Drewrite.activeRecipes=com.company.platform.recipe.spring.SpringBoot3Upgrade \
-Drewrite.recipeArtifactCoordinates=org.openrewrite.recipe:rewrite-spring:5.25.0,org.openrewrite.recipe:rewrite-apache:1.10.0,com.company:rewrite-recipe-starter:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT \
-Dproject.prerequisites.maven=3.0
-f ./pom.xml

I tried updating the configuration key value pair from
ignoredPattern: ['a.b.']

to
ignoredPattern: ['a.b.test']

to make sure . is not the last character, the exception gone.
Considering the configuration in a YAML file can vary greatly and lacks a fixed pattern, if an OpenRewrite recipe does not recognize it, it should ignore the configuration instead of throwing an exception and blocking other recipes' execution.

What is your question?
